# Factorisation of Sigma Series question

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I factorize the following? [image]

For people who can't read my hand writing it's 3/2n(n+1)(2n+1)-2n(n+1)+n, the equation comes from a sigma series question I have worked up to but I am really crap at factorizing.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You wrote a clear question and stated very well where you were struggling with, as such I upvoted your question.

Comment: Please accept an answer if you are happy with it. You could still ask some additional question in the comment section. Don't forget to accept an answer in the end (by pressing the check mark button).

Comment: @Jan could you please be friendly enough to mention whether this helped and could you, if it helped, accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at which factors (= "multiplier") are common in both parts*. $(n-1)$ seems a common factor, $2$ also and $n$ also (note that we could have written $\frac{2}{3} n (n+1) (2n+1) - 2n (n+1) + n$ as $\frac{1}{3} 2 n (n+1) (2n+1) - 2n (n+1) + n$, so you clearly see that $2$ and $n$ are factors in the left side of your expression.)

Now that you know the common factors, let's factorize and we get.

$2n (n+1) (\frac{1}{3} (2n+1) + (1 + n))$

I assume you wanted this factorization because you wrote $-2n (n+1)$ and $n$ close together and you wanted to find the factors in the part $\frac{1}{3} 2 n (n+1) (2n+1)$ and those in the part $- 2n (n+1) + n$. If you want to factorize over the three parts you can put $n$ outside. It is up to you what you want. :)

*part one is $\frac{1}{3} 2 n (n+1) (2n+1)$ and part two is $- 2n (n+1) + n$, part 1 I call the left side of my expression, part two the right side of my expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot man I can do everything else from the further pure exam but this just shits me up

Comment: Yea no problem bro ;). I Always like to help people. Hope you understand now how it works in general. What you do is, you split your expression in some parts that you choose (max. number of parts is max. number of + or - signs combined), and then you choose some common factors you want to set outside. If you have chosen those, you can easily find what would have needed to be inside the brackets. :)